# compress and send

Tags: ssh

The following works as expected:

```
ssh -t shantanu@10.10.10.100 "sudo  mysqldump --databases company test " > /home/shantanu/backup_full_101x.sql
```

When I add gzip it does not work:

```
ssh -t shantanu@10.10.10.100 "sudo  mysqldump --databases company test | gzip " > /home/shantanu/backup_full_101x.sql.gzip
```

I tried using the - after gzip and it still did not work. How do I compress the data and send it to current server?

Comment: why are you using sudo to execute mysqldump and save the dump on your own home directory? It's probably unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the options `--stdout -f` to `gzip`.

```
ssh -t shantanu@10.10.10.100 "sudo  mysqldump --databases company test | gzip --stdout -f " > /home/shantanu/backup_full_101x.sql.gzip
```